# When running ionic serve, project not being ran through webpack along with different output colors?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic4

I have noticed in a few of my projects, that as I am compiling the code through my CLI, that in some projects the output text remains all black, while others output text in black, yellow and green?

I also noticed that the top project is being ran through webpack, while the bottom is not. Is that something that is configurable?

[image: Runs through webpack, colors in CLI are present]

[image: Does not run through webpack, all black output in CLI]

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be occurring? It also looks like the bottom project (in all black) is not getting all of the same code added into the project, based off the chunks and the stencils included.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Webpack is a popular module bundler, a tool for bundling application
> source code in convenient chunks and for loading that code from a
> server into a browser
```

Webpack is responsible for bundling all the modules of your project into chunks. It transpire Typescript into JavaScript. SASS to CSS. It then creates chunks of code instead of a single file for better loading in the browser.

You can configure Webpack by following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471/

Comment: I appreciate the info, however, I am still a little confused as to why one of my Ionic projects would be running through webpack and the other is not, when they were created the same way. I just wasn't sure if I missed something in a config step originally. It appears that all my config files are the same between the two project, but I may need to double check that again.